# How to find percentage contribution of each independent variable on outcome variable in R?

Tags: importance

I am running a naive bayes classification model in R on 20 independent variables and an outcome (binary) variable.
To gain more insight on the results, I would like to find out how much each of the independent variable is contributing to the outcome variable. My main rationale of doing this is so that I can set a cut-off point (eg 80%), and variables that belong to this 80% will be kept and the bottom 20% of the variables will be deemed to be unimportant and be removed. Then i want to test the model again to see if removing these unimportant variables help to improve the performance of the model.

For example, the ranked contributions are:

var1- % contribution=40%

var2- % contribution=25%

var3- % contribution=10%

var4- % contribution=5%

.

.

var9- % contribution=2

var10- % contribution=0% where the percentages sum to 100%

I hope this example illustrates my question clearly. the ranked contributions of the first 4 variables already add up to 80% (which is my cut off point, just for illustration purposes). the rest of the variables contribute only 20% in total. So I want to rerun a model with only the top 4 variable and see if the performance will improve from that of a full model.

I know the function *varImp() in the caret package in R* calculates the variable importance for each of the variables, but it doesnt show how much each variable contributes in percentage form.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.